Can I determine if a transaction was done by someone with access to the seed phrase?
My question is, does anyone know if you can view on solscan whether a transaction was done by the person that has access to the seed phrase of the wallet or if it was through an approval or something else?
basically can you tell the difference if the account was "drained" or if it was just transfered away?

The existing answer by @user24712 is fine, but it's a good question and I thought I might be able to help:

Does anyone know if you can view on an Explorer whether a transaction was done by the person that has access to the seed phrase of the wallet or if it was through an approval or something else?

The seed phrase never gets sent, it's only used to sign transactions.

Someone could have your seed phrase, and be using it to sign transactions you don't want
Someone may not have your seed phrase, but tricked you into signing a transaction you don't want.

Either way, block Explorers just see signed transaction from your wallet address. So the answer is no - you can't tell, from a transaction, whether the person has access to your seed phrase, or has tricked you into signing something you didn't want.

no you can't. If someone has access to your private key, he can perform same transaction than you would do in your phantom wallet. Although, you can check on the blockchain if it's done through a custom program or a native program, but it gives no information about potentially compromised wallet.

so there is no difference between a transfer using a smart contract vs a normal transfer?
I used chatgpt to answer my question and it gave me the answer "Yes, there is a difference in how these transactions are recorded and displayed on Solana's blockchain:
Direct transfers are simple and clear.
Smart contract interactions are more complex and might not immediately appear as straightforward transfers unless one looks at the details or understands the smart contract's logic.
On Solscan or similar explorers, while both types of transactions are visible, *

*the smart contract interactions might require more investigation to fully understand the transfer's context.

i haven't said that there is no difference between a (custom) SC transfer vs native transfer. I said "Although, you can check on the blockchain if it's done through a custom program or a native program" => phantom uses a native program. But if your private key is compromised, the hacker could create and send a transaction exactly as phantom would do. In other words, given a specific transaction, it is impossible to know if the wallet was compromised or not (technically speaking).

wouldn't the hacker also have the private key of your wallet if he was able to perform a transaction through a smart contract you approved? Basically if a hacker was able to perform a transaction through a smart contract you approved, technically he might also have access to your private key and be able to just perform a normal transaction right?

i don't think that we can get the private key of a signer of a transaction in the program. I guess other could correct if i'm wrong. Usually private keys are stolen with malicious softwares, etc, not programs.

what I meant is if you connect your wallet somewhere or click a link or whatever, can your private key get stolen?

yes & then if your private key is stolen, the hacker could perform transfers, and you can't see if the transaction was run by the hacker or by the rightful owner

oh okay, I've heard from one my friends that he just clicked a link and his wallet on his telegram bot got drained, can the same thing happen to someone that just uses the phantom extension?

i've heard many times that clicking malicious links could be dangerous, but don't really know more than that
